# How to clear struct values except certain fields with struct's method

Tags: go

I have a struct. I want to clear all fields **except** some public fields, e.g. `Name`, `Gender`, how to implement the function through method?

*In my real code, I have many fields in the struct, so reset those sensitive fields manually is not my option.*

```golang
type Agent struct {
    Name    string
    Gender  string
    Secret1 string
    Secret2 string
}

func (a *Agent) HideSecret() {
    fmt.Println("Hidding secret...")
    new := &Agent{
        Name:   a.Name,
        Gender: a.Gender,
    }
    a = new
}
```

I tried a few combination of `*` and `&`, but it seems not working...
Please help.

```golang
    James := Agent{
        Name:    "James Bond",
        Gender:  "M",
        Secret1: "1234",
        Secret2: "abcd",
    }

    fmt.Printf("[Before] Secret: %s, %s\n", James.Secret1, James.Secret2)
    James.HideSecret()
    fmt.Printf("[After]  Secret: %s, %s\n", James.Secret1, James.Secret2) // not working
```

The golang playground is here: https://go.dev/play/p/ukJf2Fa0fPI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The receiver is a pointer. You have to update the object that the pointer points to:

```
func (a *Agent) HideSecret() {
    fmt.Println("Hidding secret...")
    cleaned := Agent{
        Name:   a.Name,
        Gender: a.Gender,
    }
    *a=cleaned
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just clear the fields, this is an easy solution. it saves some memory

```
func (a *Agent) HideSecret() {
   fmt.Println("Hidding secret...")
   a.Secret1 = ""
   a.Secret2 = ""
}
```